# Command: java -jar [...] Fails with Error Message

Tags: java, jar

I am running java 1.8.0_65 on Windows 7.
I create a JAR and run it with the following command:

`java -jar printxml.jar`

And get this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class printxml.PrintXml

Here is my command to create the JAR:

`jar cmfev manifest.txt printxml.jar printxml.PrintXml @filelist.txt`

Contents of file "manifest.txt":

> Class-Path: C:\Users\Me\SQLSER~1\JDBC\jtds-1.3.1.jar

I checked whether printxml.PrintXml class is in the JAR via this command:

`jar tvf printxml.jar printxml/PrintXml.class`

The command succeeded, i.e. PrintXml class is in the JAR.
I then checked if the PrintXml class in the JAR has a "main" method via this command:

`javap -classpath printxml.jar -public printxml.PrintXml`

The command succeeded and its output included...

> public static void main(java.lang.String[]);

Searching the Internet, I found only the obvious answers, like:

- Your classpath is wrong.
- Your class doesn't have a "main" method.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,
Avi.

Comment: Can you share the code for PrintXml and you full manifest.txt?

Comment: You forget include main class in MANIFEST.MF Look here for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: use absolute `Class-Path`  in jar file is not recommend, you can use `eclipse -> export -> jar file`  to pack all file into one executable `jar`

Comment: @RC - The full "manifest.txt is in the original post.

Comment: @Maxim - First of all, my original post does NOT contain the contents of MANIFEST.MF. Nonetheless the MANIFEST.MF contained in the generated JAR file does contain a Main-Class entry.

Comment: @Yu - I already tried your suggestion (prior to posting my original question) as well and got the same result.

Comment: @AviAbrami is right, you instead `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF ` add a `manifest.txt` file, the file name is case sensitive and must have a correct extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Homer Simpson would say: D'OH
The value of the Class-Path entry in file "manifest.txt" is wrong!
It needs to be a URL!
So I changed it to:

`file:/C:/Users/Me/SQLSER~1/JDBC/jtds-1.3.1.jar`

Hey presto! No more error message. Now it runs!
Thanks to all who helped.  ;-)

Comment: I would say RTFM is appropriate here!  :-)